# Including a radio button below text entry box in Qualtrics

Tags: qualtrics

I'm desperately trying to include a radio button beneath a text-entry question in Qualtrics. The question would look like this:

"How many jellybeans are in the picture above?"

[text box here]

[radio button here with the text "I don't know" to the right of it]

The idea is that people who have no idea how many jellybeans there are would click the Don't know button, rather than providing a crazy answer. Of course, I'm doing on a survey on economics, not jelly beans..

THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a text entry question. Use a multiple choice question. Allow text entry on the first choice, and the second choice is "I don't know".

You can write some JavaScript to hide the button/label for the first choice, but the specifics depend on the type of theme you are using.